# delphi VCL TMemo or TRichEdit с цветными полосами прокрутки готовые решения

Tags: delphi, vcl

delphi VCL TMemo or TRichEdit с цветными полосами прокрутки вертикальные и горизонтальные. Какие есть готовые решения или как раскрасить стандартные? версия 10.3

У меня есть AlMemo но там только вертикальная полоса прокрутки. можно конечно дописать что бы горизонтальная была. но все же хочется найти готовое. у меня мои нарисованые скрол бары. но их обратно же нужно приклеивать к мемо

я в нете такой код нашел. но он не работает. я не силен в Vcl  хотельсь бы узнать что не так делаю или  что можно сделать что бы цвет изменился.

```
    InitializeFlatSB(H);

    FlatSB_SetScrollRange(H,WSB_PROP_CYVTHUMB,0,100,False);
    // меняем параметры
    FlatSB_SetScrollProp(H,WSB_PROP_VSTYLE,FSB_ENCARTA_MODE,False); // плоский

    FlatSB_SetScrollProp(H,WSB_PROP_CXVSCROLL,100,False); // ширина
    FlatSB_EnableScrollBar(H,SB_VERT,ESB_DISABLE_DOWN);
    FlatSB_ShowScrollBar(H,SB_BOTH,True);
    FlatSB_SetScrollProp(H, WSB_PROP_VBKGCOLOR,RGB2BGR(145,44,255),True); // цвет фона
```

Так же попробовал сделать обработку сообщения WM_CTLCOLORSCROLLBAR
но оказалось оно вообще не присылается.

```
   TCP = class (TPanel)
     protected
       FBrush:HBRUSH;
     public
      procedure WndProc(var Message: TMessage); override;
   end;
procedure TCP.WndProc(var Message: TMessage);
begin
    case Message.Msg of
          WM_CREATE :begin
               FBrush:=  CreateSolidBrush(clblack);

          end;
          WM_DESTROY:begin
            DeleteObject(HGDIOBJ(FBrush));
          end;
          WM_CTLCOLORSCROLLBAR:begin
               Message.Result:= Integer(FBrush);
          end;

    end;
    inherited;

end;
```

Comment: Версия, не указана версия делфи, библиотек компонентов под **VCL** _(или вам нужен VLC проигрыватель?)_ - просто пачки в интернете, но раскрасить скролл бары можно без всяких библиотек.

Comment: @Владимир Клыков
подскажите как у стандартных поменять цвет TMemo же использует бары windows

Comment: Средствами vcl - onDraw или onPain не помню какой из них за отрисовку непосредственно отвечает.
 Средствами винапи - FlatSB_SetScrollProp

Comment: Думаю Вам сюда https://stackoverflow.com/a/14734945/2546083, только чтобы не было утечек, нужно создавать браш в конструкторе и удалять в деструкторе компонента https://stackoverflow.com/a/40170079/2546083

Comment: Еще можно попробовать воспользоваться темами, созцдав свою тему раскрасив скрол, правда тогда все скролы будут так выглядеть. Будет как то так https://i.imgur.com/36xYBGj.gif

Comment: @
Владимир Клыков спасибо. я поколупал итернет  FlatSB_SetScrollProp но не получилось изменить цвет. может что не так сделал. вопрос дополнил

Comment: @androschuk
так это TScrollBar отдельный компонент а нужно же в memo а в memo это системный скрол на сколько я понял такое для memo не сработает